# Graph all child nodes common lisp

Tags: graph, common-lisp

I need to find all nodes that are children of selected node. Graph is created like this:
(setq graf1 '((A(B C)) (B(D E)) (C (F G )) (D (H)) (E(I)) (F(J)) (G(J)) (H()) (I(J)) (J())))
So, all children from node B are (on first level) D,E, on 2nd H,I, third J. 
Here's the code for finding first level children, but as i'm begineer in lisp i cant make it work for other ones.

```
(defun sledG (cvor graf obradjeni)
  (cond ((null graf) '())
        ((equal (caar graf) cvor)
                (dodaj (cadar graf) obradjeni))
        (t(sledG cvor (cdr graf) obradjeni)))
(defun dodaj (potomci obradjeni)
  (cond ((null potomci) '())
        ((member (car potomci) obradjeni)
         (dodaj (cdr potomci) obradjeni )
        (t(cons (car potomci)
                (dodaj (cdr potomci) obradjeni) ))))
(setq graf1 '((A(B C)) (B(D E)) (C (F G )) (D (H)) (E(I)) (F(J)) (G(J)) (H()) (I(J)) (J())))
```

Comment: Every node is represented by a leter. Connection between nodes and their children (also nodes) are represented this way (node(child1 child2 ...)) example (A(B C)) - so here A is in car position, and yes, childer are sub-graph pointed by cdr -eg children of nodes B and C.

Comment: This is part of lisp learning exercise. This is the format of graph that i'm receiving, it cant be entered in any other form. In the end, i should print list of all nodes that are children of one selected node and distance from that node ex fo B:(D 1 E 1 H 2 E 2 J 3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [`alexandria`](http://common-lisp.net/project/alexandria/) package:

```
(defvar *graf*
  '((a (b c)) (b (d e)) (c (f g)) (d (h)) (e (i)) (f (j)) (g (j)) (h nil) (i (j)) (j nil)))

(defun descendants (tree label)
  (let ((generation
         (mapcan #'cadr
                 (remove-if-not
                  (alexandria:compose (alexandria:curry #'eql label) #'car)
                  tree))))
    (append generation (mapcan (alexandria:curry #'descendants tree) generation))))

;; (D E H I J)
```

I believe, this is what you wanted to do. This will work for acyclic graphs, but it will recur "forever", if you have a cycle in it. If you wanted to add depth counter, you could add it as one more argument to `descendants` or in the last `mapcan` transform the resulting list by inserting the depth counter.

With depth included:

```
(defun descendants (tree label)
  (labels ((%descendants (depth label)
             (let ((generation
                    (mapcan #'cadr
                            (remove-if-not
                             (alexandria:compose
                               (alexandria:curry #'eql label) #'car)
                             tree))))
               (append (mapcar (alexandria:compose
                                #'nreverse
                                (alexandria:curry #'list depth))
                               generation)
                       (mapcan (alexandria:curry #'%descendants (1+ depth))
                               generation)))))
    (%descendants 0 label)))

;; ((D 0) (E 0) (H 1) (I 1) (J 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

As I read it, the graph is a directed graph. So to find the children (directed edges) of the graph (in the example),

```
(defun children (node graph) (second (assoc node graph)))
```

then

```
(children 'b graf1) ; with graf1 from the OP
```

returns (D E). All you have to do then is to loop over the children, something like (very quick and dirty)

```
(defun all-children (node graph)
  (let ((c (children node graph)))
    (if (null c) nil
        (union c (loop for x in c appending (all-children x graph))))))
```

This returns (J I H D E) as children of B.

Comment: thanks, one more question althou: with this approach, is it possible to print depth (distance from chosen node) after node? so, for example it will be (J 3 I 2 H 2 D 1 E 1)

Comment: one of my ideas is that children returns eg: ((D E)1) and then i can do loop for (car x) [which will be (D E)] in c appending (all-children [not sure what to put here] graph)

Comment: or, maybe it's better to be ((J 3) (I 2) (H 2) (D 1) (E 1)) so that i can remove duplicates easily using remove-duplicates.